# What gets inspected and adapted? "against which X can inspect and adapt"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The [Professional Scrum Developer Glossary](https://www.scrum.org/Resources/PSD-Glossary) contains this definition:

> Engineering Standards: a shared set of development and technology standards that a Development Team applies to create releasable Increments of software, and against which a Development Team can inspect and adapt.

In this sentence are the "Engineering Standards" getting inspected and adapted?
Or do they form an immutable frame setting the boundaries for inspecting and adapting everything but the "Engineering Standards"?

Answer (score 1):

> In this sentence are the "Engineering Standards" getting inspected and adapted?

No, the "and" means that you can say: *a shared set of development and technology standards that against which a Development Team can inspect and adapt.*

> Or do they form an immutable frame setting the boundaries for inspecting and adapting everything but the "Engineering Standards"?

Nothing here about them being immutable or mutable, it just says that they are defined as the things against which you compare what you do and adapt if you find yourself deviating, i.e. if you compare your work against something and adapted then you have effectively considered that thing to be an engineering standard.

How to *establish* an engineering standard is up to you and/or your organization, but it's not part of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that the development team "inspect and adapt against Engineering Standards".  This doesn't really make sense to me: we **adapt to things**, we don't *adapt against* them and we **inspect things**, we don't *inspect against* them.  I think it's just poorly written.

I would rewrite it as

*Engineering Standards: a shared set of development and technology standards that a Development Team applies to create releasable Increments of software, and which a Development Team can inspect and adapt to.*

Comment: the intent here though is comparison, and comparison is against something, i.e. what is meant here is that we compare what we do against the engineering standard (inspect against), and adapt what we do based on those findings, there are several references of [inspect against on google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=inspect+against#tbm=bks&q=%22inspect+against%22)